# What the right way to run a ios app

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a app which connects to a heart rate strap. It is calculating bits on heart rate and logging it to a file and sending it with Json to a web server. When the app is in the foreground it displays the heart rate, speed and some extra info to the user.

Now when the app enters the background it stops the calculation and doesn't send data to the web server and also stops logging to the file.

Now the question is, what is the right way to make this app. I have now a datahandler class which handle and log the data, it is sharedInstance and it sends data to the view with postNotificationName... .

Comment: you may start the investigation by understanding the background modes in an iOS app: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: I've already read. But I would like to create a task that runs in the background and the foreground.

Comment: if you have read, you already know the limitations and you also exactly know what type of tasks can run in background-mode. unfortunately, we could not create every type of applications if we'd like to publish via AppStore. :( however you have not mentioned your plan is publishing it via Appstore, I just assumed it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I have now add UIBackgroundModes bluetooth-central mode add to my info.plist, and that work now. But is this the right way?